# Programa que cuente la cantidad de vocales de una frase en Python

Tags: python

El programa deberá solicitar el ingreso de una frase, una vez que esta se almacene en una variable deberá contas la cantidad de vocales totales y la cantidad de cada vocal que se encuentran en la frase mostrando el resultado en pantalla, la frase puede ser de cualquier longitud y puede contener cualquier símbolo.

Ejemplo:
Ingrese una frase: Hola estudiantes, éxitos en su examen
Evaluando…
Vocales A: 3
Vocales E: 6
Vocales I: 2
Vocales O: 2
Vocales U: 2
Total de Vocales: 15

Comment: Bienvenido Aldair a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: Muéstranos que es lo que has intentado y que problemas has tenido. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que así lo haría yo.

```
cadena = input("Ingrese su CUIT/CUIL: ")

vocales=[]
total=0
for i in ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]:
    vocales.append(cadena.count(i))
    total+=cadena.count(i)

print("Vocales a:",vocales[0], ", Vocales e:", vocales[1], 
      ", Vocales i:",vocales[2], ", Vocales o:",vocales[3], 
      ", Vocales U:", vocales[4],
      ", Total de Vocales:", total)
```

Ten en esto difencia entre minusculas y mayusculas.

Algunos enlaces para que puedas practicar con algunos problemas de ese estilo.:[Libro Python Cookbook](https://github.com/dabeaz/python-cookbook/tree/master/src), [Ejercicios para practicar en Python](https://projecteuler.net/).

Comment: Pero para que también enumere las vocales mayúsculas y tildada como se hace disculpe ???